# Python Docker Image Vulnerability : CVE-2023-38408 OpenSSH Vulnerable

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, image, amazon-ecr

I'm currently deploying a docker image using python 3.9.18 is there anyway to get rid of this OpenSSH critical vulnerability which is due to it not being a later version than OpenSSH 9.3p2.

Any advice would be appreciated.

I have tried multiple Python images and even tried using Python 3.10. I have also tried running the apt get and update commands for openssh but it keeps telling me that 9.2p1 is latest.

Comment: Build it from source code instead, you will get latest version.

Comment: What base image are you using?  The latest Python is 3.12.